# New rows created in Django admin aren't displayed on site

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, postgresql-9.2

This problem is noticed when doing the Django tutorial.

1. Successfully make a poll with a choice on the admin site that is then displayed on the admin site:

[image: poll successfully created on admin site]

2. Go to `mysite.com/polls` and the poll is not present:
   "No polls are available."
3. I can either `apachectl restart` or `touch mysite/wsgi.py` and get the same results which is that the new row then displays properly at `mysite.com/polls`

Why aren't the new rows displayed immediately at `mysite.com/polls` after their creation at the admin site without restarting the server?

Relevant code from urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from django.utils import timezone
from polls.models import Poll

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now) \
                .order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
            context_object_name='latest_poll_list',
            template_name='polls/index.html'),
        name='index'),
...
```

There is no code for `mysite.com/polls` in views.py.

The template code for `mysite.com/polls`

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Using:

1. Django 1.5
2. python 3.3.0-3
3. mod_wsgi 3.4-2
4. postgresql 9.2.3-1
5. apache 2.2.24-1
6. linux 3.8.4-1

Extra notes:

1. Same behavior on Django's (1.5) development server
2. Same behavior NOT present previously when I did the Django (1.5) tutorial under python 2.7 and MySQL
3. The rows are `SELECT`-able from the postgresql shell after creation at the admin site
4. The new polls are readable from the shell client when made on the admin site using `django.test.client.Client`
5. When I made a new poll from the shell using `django.test.client.Client`, the new poll was not readable from either the shell client or on `mysite.com/polls`, however it was readable from `psql` and `mysite.com/admin` before a server restart.

Comment: What code are you using to fetch polls at `mysite.com/polls`?

Answer (score 0):

Querysets in Django are usually evaluated "lazily", meaning you can write something like `Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now).order_by('-pub_date')` once, and then every time you evaluate it (try to actually get the data from it) it will go and fetch the data right at that moment.

However, adding that `[:5]` to the end evaluates it right then and there. That means what you're passing to the ListView is not actually a queryset but just a list of values; a list that is created once when the view is created and then is never reevaluated.

In order to achieve your goal, I suggest you create a custom `ListView` in `views.py` that overrides the `queryset` method. For more information on how exactly to go about that, simply check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#extending-generic-views).

Comment: This is right out of the tutorial - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial05/ . `Notice that we use a callable queryset argument, timezone.now, which will be evaluated at request time. If we had included the parentheses, timezone.now() would be evaluated just once when the web server is started.` The example also has the slice.

Comment: Huh, you are correct. My apologies. In fact, it looks like slicing a QuerySet will actually (usually) return an unevaluated QuerySet. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets You learn something new every day!

Comment: It's very possible. I believe it is also the case that django admin has somewhat shoddy timezone support; what happens when you create a poll through the interactive shell as the tutorial states? Does it work then?

Comment: Code is pretty straightforward: https://github.com/django/django/blob/f403653cf146384946e5c879ad2a351768ebc226/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1074

Comment: The tutorial/documentation is still slightly behind for python 3.x as well. You no longer use __unicode__() in the models and are to use __str__() now, which makes the tutorial tests fail. The new polls are readable from the shell when made on the admin site using `django.test.client.Client`. When I made a new poll from the shell, the new poll was not readable from either the shell client or on `mysite.com/polls`, however it was readable from `psql` and `mysite.com/admin` before a server restart.